# Is there anyway to combine two bitmaps using respective byte array or ByteArrayOutputstream

Tags: java, android, bytearrayoutputstream

It may sound silly but I started trying this just because I am curious to know how does `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `byte` Array stores information about `Bitmap`. I know that I can easily combine two or more `Bitmap` using `Canvas` but once you convert those   `Bitmap` into `ByteArrayOutputStream` (Using JPEG compression)is there any way to combine `Bitmap` using those `ByteArrayOutputStream`. I tried combining two `streams` and also respective `byte` array but I always end up getting only one bitmap as output(which bitmap comes out depends on order of combining). Can someone please explain me about how does `ByteArrayOutputStream` works.

Thank you.

Comment: They both put the information into byte arrays. If you want to combine bitmaps you are first going to have to tell us exactly what that means to you. Obesssing about implementation details of `ByteArrayOutputStream` isn't going to solve anything.

Comment: @EJP consider I have two bitmaps and I want to place one of them to the right of another and make final bitmap. Things to remember I have access only to `ByteArrayOutputStream` of those bitmaps and not to the actual bitmaps.

Answer (score -1):

This is Java!

Write one stream after the other.

```
image1.write(image2.toByteArray());
```

If you just sequentially as a single `InputStream`, you can construct a [`SequenceInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html) .

```
InputStream bothBitmaps = new SequenceInputStream(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(image1.toByteArray()),
    new ByteArrayInputStream(image2.toByteArray()));
```

Comment: What is `image2.toByteArray()`?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray()

Comment: @JordiCastilla I tried this.. I will get only one bitmap as output